# How does jQuery element.ready() works?

Tags: jquery, onload, jquery-events, document-ready

I have used Javascript for years, but never felt the need to use a library like jQuery; in the place where I work now this library is used and I found it much interesting, even if I still prefer to stick to pure Javascript.

The question has theoretical value; I am wondering how the `.ready` function works, when related to a generic element in the DOM tree.

I found threads on how `.ready()` works on the document, but this is not hard to figure out that jQuery uses somehow the DOM event `DOMContentLoaded`, easily available.

But it is less obvious the catch of the loading of a specific element in page, because, AFAIK, there is no event for that.

Because jQuery is Javascript, and we can add an event listener in every part of the document, I thing jQuery does not add a `<script>` tag after an element to handle its load event, or it won't be executed if created after the parsing passed that point.

I also thing that jQuery does not use a check based on setInterval, repetively checking if the element has been created, because it wastes much resources (especially when many elements have load events) and yet it would rarely trigger contextually with the very creation of the element.

The thing I can imagine is that, catching `DOMContentLoaded` event (so not after the element load, but after all document is loaded), jQuery calls the `.ready()` artificial events placed in the document events in the order the appear along of the DOM tree. Is that correct or jQuery has found a workaround?

I think that, inside the handler for an element, let's say of id "myelement", `$(#myelement).ready()`, if we try to `getElementById("someID")` another element that appears after `#myelement`, we obtain a correct value, instead of "undefined" as we would obtain if we were trying to get that element in a script placed inside the html after `#myelement`.

So, is `(#myelement).ready()` a fictitious event handler, which responds to all `element.ready()` events inside the `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Sorry if I wrote too much; hope I was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to http://api.jquery.com/ready/ the `ready()` function is a handler/function to execute after the DOM is ready(FULLY LOADED). Reading further on....

`.... In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready,`

Also according to the same source

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(handler)
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> $(handler)
> ```

So... the `ready()` function only applies to the `document` and not on individual elements.

Comment: I understand that claims of existence of something like `$('div').ready() or $('div').load(), bind() and similar are not suffragated with corresponding documentation. In fact, load event has the same restrictions of the DOM load event, as it should obviously be. I am sorry for misleading information I listened to